# Java DSL to set object instance in camel exchange property

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is there a one liner Java DSL to do the following:

```
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.setProperty("name", new MyBean());
    }
})
```

The goal is to have a property 'name' initialised with an new instance of MyBean class before other logic in the route.

I think it must be in the form of:

```
.setProperty("name", ... expression ...)
```

I cannot find the right expression.

Thanks.

Comment: I can make a custom expression:  
<br/>
    public static Expression newInstance(final Class clazz) {
     return new ExpressionAdapter() {
      @Override
      public Object evaluate(Exchange exchange) {
       try {
        return clazz.newInstance();
       } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot instantiate class '" + clazz.getName() + "': " + e.getMessage());
       }
      }
     };
    }

But surely there must be an existing expression..

Comment: Ahhrgg, sorry not good at the comment syntax.

Answer (score 4):

i used

```
.setProperty("name").exchange(ex -> new MyBean())
```

Answer (score -1):

yes there is.

```
from("direct:in")
    .setProperty("key").constant(new MyBean())
    .to("direct:out")
```

You can also use `.ref("bean-ref")` to refer to something in the registry

Comment: Constant will give the same object instance with each new message. This is not what i need.

Comment: Ref with the bean set to prototype will give you a new object per exchange, otherwise you need to do it with a processor like your question states, or else call a bean which does the same thing. Or if you really really want to keep in the in DSL then this might work `.setProperty("key").groovy("new foo.bar.MyBean()")`, but I didn't test it

Comment: as JStefan already stated "Constant will give the same object instance" so misleading answer